# TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role. But role is certainly supplied. Discorcd.js V13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So i am making a ticket system and i need a certain role to be able to look in the newly created channel but it keeps complaining i didn't supply a role even though i most definitely did.

I have tried the following:

```js
await interaction.guild.roles.fetch()
let helperrol = await interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === 
       rolesAndChannels.helperRol);
let modrol = await interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === 
       rolesAndChannels.moderatorRol);

await interaction.guild.channels.create(kanaalmaaknaam, {
                type: 'text',
                parent: rolesAndChannels.ticketCatagorie,
                permissionOverwrites: [{
                    id: interaction.guild.id,
                    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
                },
                    {
                        id: interaction.user.id,
                        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
                    },
                    {
                        id: helperrol,
                        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
                    },
                    {
                        id: modrol,
                        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
                    },
                ],
            }).catch('Er is een fout opgetreden bij het maken van het text kanaal');
```

But I still get the error.

I have tried:

```js
{
                        id: rolesAndChannels.moderatorRol,
                        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
                    },
```

Where `rolesAndChannels.moderatorRol` is the `roleID` but that results in the same error.

I have also tried to just supply the roleID directly but still same error.

I have enabled the partials intent if that's important.

Its a slash command.

Comment: What does it log? Do `console.log(rolesAndChannels.moderatorRol)`

Comment: Read the error carefully "...is **not a User nor a Role**" You *have* supplied *something* however it does not resolve to a user or role.

Comment: @MrMythical It returns the roleID.

Comment: @Elitezen Correct. after pulling my hair out the whole day i recoppied the role ID's and got completely diffrent ID's that do work. Thank you for taking your time to comment!

Answer (score 0):

The awnser was that I somehow copied the wrong ID's of the roles or something.
I recopied the role ID's from the settings menu and that fixed the error.